Is it possible to compute the X25519 scalar multiplication of the SSH key exchange using the ED25519 sliding window implementation?
There are many different ED25519/Curve25519/X25519 implementations around. I focus on two of them:

https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium
https://github.com/floodyberry/ed25519-donna

The libsodium library provides the function
crypto_scalarmult_curve25519_ref10(unsigned char *q,
                                   const unsigned char *n,
                                   const unsigned char *p)

in the file x25519_ref10.c which is e.q. used during the SSH handshake to exchange a secret using ECDH.
The ed25519-donna provides a very fast implementation of ed25519 and also provides the function
/*
Fast Curve25519 basepoint scalar multiplication
*/

void
ED25519_FN(curved25519_scalarmult_basepoint) (curved25519_key pk, const curved25519_key e) {

...
Unfortunately this doesn't yield the same result as the x25519 scalar multiplication from libsodium.
Now the question:
Is there a way to implement the scalar multiplication of X25519 by using the ed25519 functions? And how would an implementation look like?

Yes, but it would be slower.  Ed25519 and Curve25519 are isomorphic (if you handle Curve25519's degenerate points correctly), so you can convert between the two.  It gets a bit complicated, but it can be done.  However, there's not much reason to do this - just use a Curve25519 implementation.

@Myria: would it be a speedup then to use Curve25519 for Ed25519 computations?
